# Время, которое сотрудник провел на рабочем месте

Tags: sql

Есть таблица с полями: `Personal_number, Surname, Name, Patronunic, Permit_number, Pass-kind`, значения которой заносятся обычным insert.

Cмысл в том, что когда человек проходит через кпп система фиксирует его (личный номер, фамилия, имя, отчество, номер пропуска) время прохода и вид прохода (имеется виду тот факт, вошел он или вышел). Эти значения и вносятся в таблицу

Суть запроса: нужно вывести время, которое сотрудник провел на рабочем месте, т.е. разницу во времени между строкой с значением "exit" и строкой с значением "enter" в полях Pass_Kind соответственно.

*Обнвление*

Работаю в Microsoft Sql Server.

Формально, мне нужно получить табличку, в которой останутся все прежние поля, а в поле Pass_Time (которое я по собственной глупости забыл указать) будет стоять время, проведенное на рабочем месте (т.е. результат вычитания времен).

*Обновление 2*

Пробовал вот так

```
select Personal_Number, 
Assistance_Surname, 
Assistance_Name, 
Assistance_Patronymic, 
Permit_Number , Pass_Kind, (t2.COUNT-t1.COUNT) as Working_Time from (select t1.Personal_Number, t1.Assistance_Surname, t1.Assistance_Name, t1.Assistance_Patronymic, t1.Permit_Number, t1.Pass_Kind as t1 t2.Personal_Number,  t2.Assistance_Surname,  t2.Assistance_Name,  t2.Assistance_Patronymic, t2.Permit_Number,  t2.Pass_Kind as t2
from ((select * from Date_Pass  where Pass_Kind='exit') union
                                                                                    (select * from Date_Pass  where Pass_Kind='enter')) as t) where t1.Personal_Number=t2.Personal_Number AND t1.Assistance_Surname=t2.Assistance_Surname AND  
                                                                                                                                t1.Assistance_Name=t2.Assistance_Name AND t1.Assistance_Patronymic=t2.Assistance_Patronymic AND
                                                                                                                                t1.Permit_Number=t2.Permit_Number AND t1.Pass_Kind=t2.Pass_Kind
```

Comment: Запрос где? Что не получается? Или вычесть одно время из другого не получается? Какая СУБД? Или вы думаете здесь все обладают экстрасенсорными способностями?

Comment: Просто сделацйте выборку всех строк, в которой повится дополнительная колонка с разностью двух времен, затем из нее сделайте выборку с суммированием по этому полю и группировкой по полям, идентифицирущим персону.

Comment: Аналогичная задача была: [Запрос к базе данных с логами работы телефонного аппарата](http://hashcode.ru/questions/125575/sql-запрос-к-базе-данных-с-логами-работы-телефонного-аппарата)

Comment: Такое тестовое задание дают в "чистой воде"